# How to get these moving average results

Tags: r, datatables, rolling-average

I am trying to get moving average in this format

Where NA stays NA otherwise show average of three periods but for the first and second period assume the missing values to be extension of existing value.

I am trying the rollmean and rollapply functions with varying inputs but not the results I want.

```
tempo[,toto:= rollmean(original,3,align="left", fill="extend")]
tempo[,toto1:= rollapply(original,3,mean,align="left", na.pad=FALSE)]


tempo<-data.table(original = c(NA,NA,NA,10,0,0,0,10,10,10,0,NA,NA),
                  desired = c(NA,NA,NA,10,5,3.3,0,3.3,6.6,10,6.6,NA,NA))
```

Comment: The exact output expected is the "desired" column in the data table. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, sorry, yeah ... (face-palm ... put the beer down ...)

Comment: Why a -1 on the last couple rows? That violates your rule of *"`NA` stays `NA`"*.

Comment: Frankly,  your first `10` doesn't make sense to me, either ... if it's left-aligned width-3, then wouldn't you have `c(NA, NA, 3.3333, ...)`?

Comment: Please clarify the rules and show for each of the desired results how it was obtained.  `rollapplyr(original, 3, mean, na.rm = TRUE, fill = NA)` gives the correct result for most entries so either the others represent an error in the question or else the rules are not clear.

Comment: @r2evans corrected the end NA's. The first 10 is a valid requirement. Made some other data corrections in desired as well.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck, your solution works like a charm. Can you submit this as an answer and I will accept it. Thanks so much!